# Getting Facebook User in Asp .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I have an asp .net web application. There are some user actions that I want to follow along with the user's facebook id. What is the best and shortest way to get the logged in facebook user id ? I have googled it, there are many code segments but I couldn't find any complete asp .net exapmles.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use www.facebook.com/developers and get the help from their....
All the things are mentioned their....
You would have to use fql with facebook authentication

Comment: i already checked but i could not find any documentation about asp .net. I tried to install facebook developer toolkit but i got some problems, so i thought there may be a simpler way for that.Thanks.

Comment: Open a new question and explain those problems.  This question is way to broad.